# UUID V4 GENERATION USING ESQL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a scenario where I need to generate UUID V4 using ESQL. I know UUIDASCHAR generates UUID, but unable to determine if it is V1 or V4.

Is it possible to generate UUID V4 using ESQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether ESQL can generate v4 UUIDS, but I'm sure there is a Java class library that can do it. It may even be available in the built-in JVM libraries that ship with ACE, in which case it should be very easy to call the required method from ESQL.

Comment: I reached out to IBM and they said that at the moment they only generate UUID V1 using the UUIDASCHAR function in ESQL, and they will take it as an improvement to generate V4. In java it is possible to generate V4 using the util package, but I have never used java. Even though I have installed java in my system, I have not been able to locate the util.jar file in windows. I want to import that to my toolkit. Do you have any idea where to find it? It is not present under the java installation folder.

Comment: Just changes some project runtime references and was able to import the java.util package to my code.

Answer (score 0):

No external dependencies are required to be imported to IIB10, ACE12 toolkit to access the Java.Util package. Just update the application references in the toolkit to use the inbuilt java version and them simply import the package to a Java compute node using standard java import statement.